# How is the "e" parameter assigned to the event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I can see a few threads around the `e` parameter but there is one thing I can't fully understand, though I'm sure it's an obvious answer.

When the `e` parameter is passed into a function that's called from `addEventListener()` the `e` looks to be assigned to the event object. What I'm trying to understand is where/how is it assigned?

```
element.addEventListener('click', function (e){
  console.log(e);
}, false);
```

Comment: Well, your handler is called with `handler(new Event(...))` when the event occurs. The argument is passed to the function exactly the same way when you call a function.

Comment: What do you mean? `e` is simply a parameter, you could name it `param`. When you add an event listener, the function that you use will be called. So if you `addEventListener('click', func1);`, then `func1(eventData)` will be called, where `eventData` is an `new Event()` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens internally, because [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener-invoke) says so:

> Call *listener*'s **callback**'s `handleEvent`, with the event passed
>   to this algorithm as the first argument and *event*'s
>   [`currentTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-currenttarget) attribute value as [callback this value](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-callback-this-value).

So the callback function receives an argument. You can name it `e`, `event`, or `foobar`. You can even not name it, and access it with `arguments[0]`.

Comment: And this has provided further clarity. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is assigned when the function is called from the event. You are just defining a callback, not calling it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function (e){
   console.log(e);
},false);
```

You could write:

```
function DoOnClick(parameter) {
  console.log(parameter);
}

element.addEventListener('click', DoOnClick ,false);
```

The second parameter from the addEventLinster, in this case, is the **callback function**. The callback function is the function that will be called when that event occurs and it will be called with a `new Event()` as the parameter, `Event parameter` that will contain all the data generated by that event (X,Y position, element it was triggered on, etc).

There is nothing special about the `DoOnClick` function, if you call it like this `DoOnClick("Hello")`, then `Hello` will be printed in the console.

If you want to know more about how the `addEventListener` actually works, you can see the [Mozilla documentation for this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thanks, Cristy! This has definitely cleared things up for me. Appreciate your help.